# Passing a variable from main() to module

Tags: python, variables, module

I have a variable (var2) within main() that I would like to access from a function in an imported module, without passing it as an argument. I have tried importing vartest.py from within module.py, and I can access var1 (that is outside main()), but not var2 from using the printFromModule2() function.

I suppose I have two questions:

1. Can this be achieved?
2. What would be the correct way of working, if this is not something that I 'should' be doing?

Many thanks!

Edit: I have tried importing vartest.py in the module, and can access vartest.var1, but not vartest.var2 or vartest.main.var2-- not sure if the 2nd of those is valid Python, however.

vartest.py:

```
import sys
import module

var1 = 'variable 1 in vartest.py'
def main():
    var2 = 'variable 2 inside main'

    print var1
    print var2
    print module.var3
    module.printFromModule(var1)
    module.printFromModule(var2)
    module.printFromModule(module.var3)
    module.printFromModule2()

if __name__ == "__main__": main()
```

module.py:

```
var3 = 'variable inside module'

def printFromModule(var_x1):
    print ("module print: %s" % var_x1)

def printFromModule2():
    print ("module print: %s" % var2)
```

Comment: You cannot access a function-local variable outside of that function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around with possible `import` options, I cannot get this to work no matter what I do. Even if I make `var2` a global variable, and use `from module import printFromModule2` to bring everything into the same global namespace, it will not work for me.

This is not really a good way of programming anyway, though. Using global variables wherever they aren't specifically required is frowned upon in most languages, and when you try using them across different modules then you're asking for trouble. Passing in parameters really is the best way to go.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation-- I am still learning the best practices, so this is valuable info. Will stay away from global variables and pass more.

Comment: @Oli that's a good idea. As you program more you'll learn the few scenarios where globals are really useful (like with mutex locks) but it's better to stay away when you can.